# Checking whether a variable is set in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a JS function that says whether a variable is set. I've defined isset() below.

It behaves strangely as described in the comments. Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          function isset(variableName) {
            return typeof variableName != 'undefined';
          }

          a = 5;
          console.log(isset(a)); 
          console.log(isset(b)); // returns an error.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `variableName` is not the same as `varname`. Why try to access an undeclared variable?

Comment: Thanks! Now the output makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Since you changed the code, change your code comment too since it should now return `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to perform the `typeof` check directly, not inside a function.

The reason is exactly the same one like in PHP (where your function would also break unless you used pass-by-reference):

`isset(b)` results in an exception being thrown because `b` is an undefined variable and passing it as an argument tries to read it which you cannot do. So the `typef` check is never executed.

Comment: But inside of my isset() function, isn't there a local variable "a" with a value of 5?